# "Unable to get term attr: Invalid argument" while trying to SCP

Tags: centos, ldap, replication, scp

I have to set up two LDAP servers for replication.
My problem is that when i want to copy the master-slapd's database files with scp command i get the next message after typing in the account's password on the slave server:
"Unable to get term attr: Invalid argument"

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

At least with OpenLDAP, you shouldn't replicate by copying files but by using the `syncrepl` mechanism.